# Unable to set storage size for an AWS database cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-lambda

I'm attempting to find a solution for this [AWS restore_db_cluster_from_snapshot yet no instances](https://serverfault.com/questions/886217/aws-restore-db-cluster-from-snapshot-yet-no-instances/886233#886233) however when I try to run the `create_db_instance` method I get the following error -

`*** ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the CreateDBInstance operation: The requested DB Instance will be a member of a DB Cluster. Set storage size for the DB Cluster.`

Here is what I have so far -

```
client = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region)
source_snaps = client.describe_db_cluster_snapshots(DBClusterIdentifier = 'main-production')['DBClusterSnapshots']
source_snap = sorted(source_snaps, key=byTimestamp, reverse=True)[0]['DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier']

response = client.restore_db_cluster_from_snapshot(
  DBClusterIdentifier='main-development',
  SnapshotIdentifier=source_snap,
  Port=port,
  Engine='aurora-postgresql')

i = client.create_db_instance(
  DBName='main',
  DBInstanceIdentifier='main-development',
  DBInstanceClass='db.r4.large',
  Engine='aurora-postgresql',
  MasterUsername='mab_admin',
  MasterUserPassword='mypassword',
  AllocatedStorage=20,
  DBClusterIdentifier='main-development')
```

I dont see anywhere in the API docs where you can set a cluster's storage size though.

Comment: I think this is a bad error message and you just need to drop the "AllocatedStorage" parameter. The docs state that it doesn't apply to aurora.

Comment: I tried removing that parameter but now I'm receiving a `** ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the CreateDBInstance operation: The requested DB Instance will be a member of a DB Cluster. Set master user password for the DB Cluster.` error despite passing in `MasterUserPassword`

Comment: I was able to figure it out btw. Like you said, it isn't the best worded error message. When it says `Set master user password for the DB Cluster` it means quit trying to set the password on the instance, do it on the cluster.